# In Snowflake, I would like to find the whole conversation grouped by the same session ID that contains a keyword

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Session_ID | USER_INPUT                                  |  STATUS_CODE

*********1 | hi                                          | OK
*********1 | I would like to know how much item A is     | OK
*********2 | Hello?                                      | OK
*********1 | whatever                                    | INVALID
*********2 | How are you doing                           | OK
*********2 | I'd like to get some info on...             | OK
```

This is an example of the snowflake table I have. I'd like to query the whole conversation grouped by "Session_ID" that contains the STATUS_CODE "INVALID."

In this case above, *********1 3 interactions and *********2 coexists. But *********1 contains (or ends with) "INVALID." I'd like to query those conversations with the same SESSION_ID.

What would be the easiest way to do this? I've tried using

```
row_number() over (partition by SESSION_ID order by DATE_TIME ASC) as SESSION_GROUP
```

the following and works but I don't know how to selectively query using the keyword "INVALID." This basically pulls everything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery to get session ids and then `IN` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE SESSION_ID IN (SELECT t.SESSION_ID FROM tab t WHERE t.STATUS_CODE = 'INVALID');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional count to get the number of "invalid"s for each session.  Then just filter:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count_if(status_code = 'INVALID') over (partition by session_id) as num_invalid
      from t
     ) t
where num_invalid > 0;
```

Actually, an even easier method uses `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify count_if(status_code = 'INVALID') over (partition by session_id) > 0;
```

In both of these cases, you probably want to add an `order by` column to order by the `session_id` and some sort of timestamp or session ordering column.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the latter one and it worked the way I wanted.